# Rails asking for "end", but everything has an end?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ok, so I am trying to learn Rails by watching YouTube; so far I am having a better understanding as I go along.

Problem is, I am using Rails 4 whereas the vidoe uses Rails 3. No big deal. There was a problem with the video's code, so someone posted in the comments section some corrected code.

Problem is, I get this error:

```
SyntaxError in PostsController#create
/home/chris/blog/app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:43: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
```

Now I've gone through my code, looked it all over, and from what I do know of Rails so far, everything has an appropriate end. I have used comments and, for every beginning, there is an 'end'. But I have definitely messed something up. And yes this is Rails 4.0 I am using.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController#main
  def index#1
    @posts=Post.all
  end#1

  def create#2
    @post=Post.new(post_params)

    if @post.save#2.1
      redirect_to posts_path, :notice =>"Your post was successfully saved"
    else
      render "new"
    end#2.1
  end#2

  def new#3
    @post=Post.new
  end#3

  def edit#4
  end#4

  def show#5
    @post=Post.find(params[:id])
  end#5

  def update#6
  end#6

  def destroy#7
  end#7

  private
  def post_params#1
    @allow = [:title, :content]
    params.require(:post).permit(@allow)
  end#1
end#main
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be a stealth [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) character between `end#` and `#1` near the end. Here's how it looks on my editor:

[image]

Deleting that line and typing it again fixed it for me.

Comment: This completely fixed it! Thanks! By the way, is that Sublime? Might switch over(using standard Ubuntu text editor).

Comment: @user3285714 It's Vim :)